# Upper Confidence Bounds in Monte Carlo Tree Search when plays or visited are 0

Tags: algorithm, search, tree

I'm looking at the 'Monte Carlo Tree Search' algorithm's 'Upper Confidence Bounds'.

```
C is a weight for exploration over exploitation.
score = wins / played
sum = wins + played
UCB = score + C * sqrt(naturalLog(parent's sum) / sum)
```

The issue occurs when played is 0. I'm considering these possibilities.

```
score = 0
Because the node has never won, although it's never lost either.

score = 0.5
Because the node's value is completly uncertain and 0.5 is half way.
```

Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: There is a logarithm missing in your formula (and a constant)

Comment: In "Ui = vi + c * sqrt((ln N)/ni)" the "ln N" part means logarithm of N?

Comment: Yes. It is basically a measure of entropy. The sqrt (ln(...))) can be thought of as an estimate for (standard) deviation. The c is the number of stddevs ("confidence") you intend to use as a safety bound/treshold.

Comment: ty, I've updated the formuli above with this correction. The main question remains.

Comment: There is a paper, claiming that a beta-distribution fits better(gives better confidence intervals) for very small samples, but I cannot not find it. It was published about 3 years ago. BTW, normally they use natural logarithms (though the c could catch the slack)

Comment: ty, changed to using naturally based log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first step in every bandit algorithm, including MCTS, is to pull every arm once.  Since this would obviously result in exhaustive search if you do this at every node, you instead only use MCTS up to a fixed depth and use a roll-out policy for the rest.  You can use a prior of course, but then you lose all the nice theoretical properties of the UCB algorithm, primarily logarithmic regret.

Comment: That isn't quite correct. The idea is that you if there is unpulled arm, pull it, otherwise use UCB. You never pull multiple arms of a single node during 1 playout.

Answer (score 1):

It is all about entropy. Without observations (N=0) the variance is undefined (undetermined), and the confidence bounds are infinite. You can't get information out of nothing.

You might correct by using a prior, or by adding a small correction just to avoid dividing by zero or taking the logarithm of zero. Or by doing a minimal amount of probes. Usually nodes only get expanded once their N reaches some limit (10...100).